# C# The checksum calculation does not give the desired calculation result

Tags: c#

I am creating an application that makes a serial connection with a communication device.

I'm creating a process to calculate the checksum, but I'm having trouble getting the desired value.

I created the code below.
Test data1 and test data2 are prepared as a pseudo data assuming data sent from a communication device.

```
    public static void GetCheckSum()
    {
        // test data1 
        // the desired checksum value(correct answer) : 61
        // This data gives 61
        // var hexInput = "43-33-30-30-20-20-20-20-20-20-20-32-03";

        // test data2
        // the desired checksum value(correct answer) : 42
        var hexInput = "54-33-30-30-20-20-20-20-38-2E-30-03";

        byte[] byteData = hexInput.Split("-").Select(hex => Convert.ToByte(hex)).ToArray();

        byte checkSumTest = new byte();

        for (int i = 0; i < byteData.Length; i++)
        {
            checkSumTest = (byte)(checkSumTest ^ byteData[i]);
        }

        Console.WriteLine(checkSumTest);
    }
```

The communication device adds 61 to test data1 and sends it.
61 was obtained by this process.

The communication device adds 42 to test data2 and sends it.
But test data2 contains "2E" in hexInput, so Convert.ToByte() gives an error.

```
System.FormatException: 'Input string was not in a correct format.'
```

I modified the code as below to solve this problem.

```
byte[] byteData = hexInput.Split("-").Select(hex => Convert.ToByte(hex, 16)).ToArray();
```

The error was resolved, but the calculated value is 66, which is different from the checksum value of 42 sent from the communication device.

What do I need to do to get the value 42?

I'm new to serial communication, so am I fundamentally misunderstanding?

Sorry for the elementary question.

Comment: What is the device's definition of the checksum?

Comment: Are you sure that the problem isn't just how you're looking at the checksum? 0x42 = decimal 66... that could be a coincidence, or it could explain the problem.

Comment: @Richard Barraclough
Horizontal parity 8-bit XOR and communication equipment manuals.
Sorry if I didn't answer your question...

Comment: @Jon Skeet
I also checked test data1 with the modified code.
The calculated result is 97, which is 61 in hex...
As you point out, I'm not sure if this is a coincidence or a solution, as there are only two samples.

I don't have it at hand now, but the manual for the communication equipment included multiple samples of the data being sent, so I'll check to see if it matches those values.

Comment: Okay, so it sounds like this really is *just* about how you're interpreting the results. It doesn't help that your question starts with broken code that you've already fixed... it's highly confusing. But basically if you change `Console.WriteLine(checksumTest)` to `Console.WriteLine($"{checksumTest:x2}")` then I think you might see the expected results...